# Can Conditional AD access be used to restrict the access to azure portal to disallow users from a certain locations from accessing the portal?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azureportal

I am a developer working for an EU region customer and am based out of India.

now - I don't want my azure portal to be accessible directly from my browser but should be able to access it from an Azure VM provisioned in the EU region.

Can this be achieved using Azure AD conditional access?

Also - If possible - what are different kind of hardening methods that can be used to ensure no data leakage is possible by copying data from this VMA to my local machine ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use **conditional access** policies to restrict access to Azure Portal for users from specific locations.

Make sure to acquire at least `Azure AD Premium P1` license that supports conditional access feature.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

Create one **named location** by selecting your region to ***exclude*** it from blocking access like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Security -> Conditional Access -> Named locations*

[image]

You can also create **named location** by specifying the `IP addresses` that you want to allow Azure Portal access from like below:

[image]

Now create one **conditional access** policy by following below steps:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Security -> Conditional Access -> Policies -> New Policy***

Enter the policy name and include the `users/groups` on which you want to apply policy on like below:

[image]

In "Cloud apps or actions" tab, make sure to select **Microsoft Azure Management** app like below:

[image]

In **Conditions** tab, include all locations and exclude the location by selecting the ***named location*** that you created earlier like below:

[image]

In Access controls, Select **Block access** and create the policy as below:

[image]

When users of ***different*** locations tried to login to Azure Portal, they will get **error** like below:

[image]

**Reference:** [Conditional Access - Block access - Azure Active Directory | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-policy-block-access)